# Do I require a 64-bit version of sqljdbc4.jar

Tags: java, sql-server, servlets, jdbc

We have a Java servlet running on Windows through Tomcat and a recent SQL server database migration caused issues that have so far been resolved by upgrading the sqljdbc to sqljdbc4.jar.  This has worked fine on 32bit operating systems but it still seems to hang and timeout on a 64 bit server.  The top error message in the logs is;

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

Is there a 64bit version of this driver?  So far I have not found one.  Is there something else that I have configured wrong?

Comment: Is your setup trying to use either Windows Authentication (`integratedSecurity=true`) or [XA Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)? There aren't 32-bit and 64-bit .jar files but there *are* 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the .dll files that support those two features.

Comment: @GordThompson I must be using XA transactions as we are not using Windows Authentication.  We are using a dedicated user credentials.  Do I still need the authentication dll?  I found this URL regarding the XA authentication, is this correct?  https://sqlserverfinebuild.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Java%20DBC%20Driver

Comment: @GordThompson Im a bit confused about this though because we have managed to get the connection to work on a development machine without tweaking authorisation dll's.  The only difference with the server with the issue is that it is outside our network??

Comment: Then I suspect that the "bitness" of the servers is probably not the issue. I would start by verifying that the Java server can actually talk to the remote SQL server using something more straightforward like odbcad32.exe, osql, or even SSMS. Once you've confirmed that (i.e., ruled out firewall issues, port forwarding, etc.) *then* you can concentrate on your JDBC configuration.

Comment: @GordThompson. Yes. I think I can confirm the bitness is not an issue as discovered it is 32 bit version of JRE is running on the server.  Also just found a way I can check connection using SQL Developer by configuring it to use the sqljdbc4.jar and it states the following message "Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall".  I will investigate odbcad32.exe but I am thinking now it is a network infrastructure problem with new MSSQL database server

Answer (score 0):

Generally jar files are platform independent. A jar containing class files can be used on 32 and 64 bit JVM.

Your problem could be that you still need the suitable JDBC driver. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

It states that you need `sqljdbc_<version>_enu.exe` installed. I'm guessing there is a difference between version 3 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, I didn't think there were 32 bit and 64 bit jars. I have the driver version sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.exe although the instructions say to install when it really just unzips.  Am I doing something wrong with the sqljdbc exe file.  I downloaded it from here; http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774